# How to change UIButton Background Image on UITableView didSelectRow without Reloading

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I added a `**UIButton**` in **UITableView Cell**. And I wantto add a functionality on both clicks (UIButton and `UITable - didSelectRow`).

On Button Click I am able to change the button background image by Sender.
The Code is look like this:

```
-(void)tableButton_OnClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

And the same functionality I want to add on `UITable - didSelectRow` without Reloading the table.

Comment: check this [SampleCode_Accessory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Ok. Got the solution - 

UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[filterTable viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own custom `UITableViewCell` with public `@property` `UIButton`. Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you may use something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourCell* yourCell = (YourCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton* button = yourCell.button;
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Ok. Got the solution - 

UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[filterTable viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

STEPS - try this

1. while adding button on cell ,set the tag value to your button

   eg :

   btn.tag=indexpath.row;
      cell.tag=indexpath.row;
2. On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, Create UIButton based on tag value
   eg:

   ```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
    {

    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[self.TableView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];

    [self tableButton_OnClick:btn];

     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[[myarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"key_name"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
   {
     [cell.button_my setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   }

   els
{

 [cell.button_my setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first_other.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        }
```